# Vim to print file on terminal and exit

Tags: vim

I would like vim to do this in order to have syntax highlight as set up in vim (or  without need for extra tools). So instead to use `cat file | <some_sh_tool>` I would use `vim +"some_opts" +"..." +q file`. The problem is that vim restores previous screen upon exit, but using some remote access tools this didn't happen so it was basically working as cat with syntax highlight.

So, is this possible ?

**EDIT**

Thinking more about this I think this is great thing to have. Apart from syntax highlighting other features of vim could be used while displaying file content, like line numbers, white space, wrapping,etc... especially within script and because vim is omnipresent.

Comment: use GNU screen.

Comment: its not exactly the same, you can't use it within script, besides, sometimes you can't choose.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408134/utilizing-emacs-or-vims-syntax-highlighter-for-command-line-program/13424531#13424531

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found exactly what I needed in a package called [vimpager](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager).

It ships with vimcat utility.

Comment: Excellent: `brew install vimcat && vimcat myscript.sh` gives syntax highlighting precisely like vim does. Couldn't hope for anything better!

Answer (score 14):

You can disable the alternate screen, by telling that the code to enable it for this terminal is the empty string like:

```
vim --cmd 'set t_ti= t_te=' ...
```

But you'll find you need more. Try:

```
vim --cmd 'set t_ti= t_te=' +redraw +q file
```

as a start.

Comment: It may pay to explain how to create an alias for the final command.

Comment: @cjh: that depends on the user's shell.

Comment: `alias catx='vim --cmd "set t_ti= t_te=" +redraw +q'` then simply run `catx infile`

Comment: you might also want to add `+"colo colorscheme"` before the `+redraw`.

Comment: Not good. It will show first page and exit. I need it to show all of the lines. Adding +$ before redraw shows first and last page only.

Comment: I also tried adding it `+"set lines=1000"` but produced some strange result...

Comment: Adding `"map <F8> <C-E>j<F8>` would make F8 autoscroll till the end, what needs to be done is to execute this hotkey from the command line... don't know how to do that

Comment: I am super late, but can we save this to a pdf using something like  `vim --cmd 'set t_ti= t_te=' +redraw +q infile  hardcopy > a.ps ?`

Comment: I very like these answers and comments. My "improvement" is commandline: `lines=$(wc -l yourFile); lines=$((${lines:0:3}+11));vim --cmd "set t_ti= t_te=" +"set lines=$lines" +redraw +q yourFile`, but I don't know how to make alias out of it. ((wc -l tells how many lines the file has. And +11 may vary on your system.))

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [`enscript`](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/) - it has syntax highlighting styles for a couple of languages and is intended to be used as a filter, and the output is not limited to just ANSI escape formatting sequences - it can also output PostScript, HTML or RTF.

Comment: I have vim setup the way I want already - colors, languages etc... some of the sh features for rare languages are custom - Csound, AutoHotKey, etc... I don't wont to write config files for another tool again.

Comment: @majkinetor sure, it all depends on what exactly you want to use it for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are constrained by your system and cannot install additional programs, then this will work. Thanks to bogec for starting a good path, now I've finished it by adding the following "alias" into my `/root/.bashrc` then reinit session and voila.

```shell
catt() {
    local lines
    lines=$(wc -l "$1" | awk '{print $1}')
    lines=$((lines + 11))
    vim --cmd "set t_ti= t_te=" +"set lines=$lines" +redraw +q "$1"
    stty sane
    printf '\033[?1000l'  # Disable mouse reporting (if enabled)
    printf '\033[?1002l'  # Disable mouse reporting (if enabled)
}
```

Usage:

```shell
catt your_file.py
```

Works perfect, just as intended.

[image: PoC][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMwRI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works for me:

Say I want to print out the contents of file "file.py" to STDOUT with all the vim settings.  I can write this:

`vim --not-a-term -T ansi +silent\ %print +redraw +quit file.py`

It's not short, but it works.  And if you want to pipe it through "less", I recommend using the `-R` switch with `less`, like this:

`vim --not-a-term -T ansi +silent\ %print +redraw +quit file.py | less -R`

(You may have to resize the terminal if the text shows up oddly spaced.)

If you want to add additional settings/commands, add them in between the `-T ansi` and the `+silent\ %print` parameters.  For example, if you want to run `:set list`, do so like this:

`vim --not-a-term -T ansi +set\ list +silent\ %print +redraw +quit file.py`

or:

`vim --not-a-term -T ansi "+set list" +silent\ %print +redraw +quit file.py`

(Remember that because "set list" contains a space, you have to either escape out the space, or surround the "+set list" command in quotes.)